# How to change background of a textview in a custom listview for each row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter, android-adapter

I created an application for chat between two person

- first of all i have to fetch all data from server by Jsonparser
- there is a custom listview each row contains "shop,painter,datetime,comment,id"
- if yourname is not empty means comment is yours and viseversa
- i want to put a bubble background for comment that indicate the painter or shop

i dont know how to use getview when i have a custom listview with more than one textview and because my resource data that is contain all information comes from server and store it to the hashmap array... hashmap doesnt have position as it is in getview method...

.........some code .....

```
// adding HashList to ArrayList
AllCommentsList.add(map);



adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                        AllCommentsList, R.layout.list_row_order_comments,
                        new String[] { TAG_COMMENT_ID, TAG_SHOP, TAG_PAINTER,TAG_COMMENT, TAG_DATETIME },
                        new int[] { R.id.tvIdComments, R.id.tvShopSender,R.id.tvPainterSender, R.id.tvComment,R.id.tvDateTimeComments });
                // updating listview
                listViewComment.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is my code but i want to dynamically change the background of Comment textview

how to put some code like this????

```
   if (strPainter.equals("null")) {
    tvComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);
    }
   if (strShop.equals("null")) {
    tvComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `SimpleAdapter`.  Create a custom adapter that overrides `getView` and make whatever manipulations that you want to the layout, background, etc based on the current item.

See `/samples/android-8/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List5.java` in your Android SDK folder (download appropriate samples as necessary) for a simple example:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv;
        if (convertView == null) {
            tv = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, parent, false);
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
        }
        tv.setText(mStrings[position]);
        return tv;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: i dont know how to use getview() when my resource is a hashmap without position, would you please provide me with a code?

Comment: @HosseinMansouri Unless you're showing comments in random order, I suspect that somewhere in the chain there's an ordered data structure.  Use that.